# React Redux authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux

I have the following situation, I have a REST API and a React+Redux application.

When the user login I'm saving the token to the localStorage, based on that, if the user comes back to the page I make a call to the server `/api/whoami { token }` with the token, there I validate the token and return the user details which I will use to update my Redux store.

My problem is that if I refresh and I want to do something in `componentDidMount`, even if the user is logged in the Redux store isn't updated yet because the request to `/api/whoami` is not finished.

How can I wait until the request to `/api/whoami` is done and the user is set then render my application?

Is there any other solution for this kind of issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use, what is called as an **Aync action** in your case, and show a loading component while the details are fetched.

Here you will have to use the **thunk middleware**. It comes in a separate package called `redux-thunk`. When an action creator returns a function, that function will get executed by the Redux Thunk middleware. Read in more detail [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html)

**Functioning:** Before you start the fetch operation, dispatch and action which sets the `isLoading` to `true` and after you have received your response you dispatch another action which will set `isLoading: false` and on your display just put a condition that if the isLoading is true you return a loading component else you return the profile component

Comment: I'm already doing this but how can I wait for the request to be finished to render my app?

Comment: your last comment should be added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you know `react-redux` and you are familiar to some concepts like `action`, `store`, `reducer`.

> How can I wait until the request to `/api/whoami` is done?

Use a **middleware** like `redux-thunk`, `[redux-saga][1]`... i recommend you to use `redux-saga` because it is a library that aims to make side effects (i.e. asynchronous things like data fetching and impure things like accessing the browser cache) in React/Redux applications easier and better.

> How the user is set then render my application?

With using **middleware**, you can render the loading view while the request is running and render what you want when the request has finished.

Read `redux-saga` offical document for more infomation and usage example.